# 500 equals 400 passes in a mocha test?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

Why does the following test pass?

```
"use strict";

const
    path = require('path'),
    Dexter = require('../src/Dexter.js'),
    chai = require('chai'),
    chaiHttp = require('chai-http'),
    expect = chai.expect,
    dexterServer = new Dexter(path.resolve(__dirname, 'test/data/sample.har'));

chai.use(chaiHttp);
describe('Rest API', () => {
    before(() => {
        dexterServer.startUp();
    });

    it('should\'ve started the server', function () {
        chai.request('http://127.0.0.1:1121')
            .get('/')
            .end(function(err, response){
                console.log(response.status);
                expect(500).to.equal(400);// This passes? What?
                done();
            });
    });

    after(() => {
        dexterServer.tearDown();
    });
});
```

When I do a console.log of the response.status, I see a 200. But when I do

```
expect(response.status).to.equal(400);//response.status is an int
```

passes the test!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass done callback. `it` was treated as sync with 0 assumptions.

```
it('should\'ve started the server', function (done) {
    chai.request('http://127.0.0.1:1121')
        .get('/')
        .end(function(err, response){
            console.log(response.status);
            expect(500).to.equal(400);// This passes? What?
            done();
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I had to pass in `done`! That fixed my test!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `done` in `it`, `before` and `after` statement to maintain the asynchronous flow.

```
describe('Rest API', (done) => {
before(() => {
    dexterServer.startUp();
});

it('should\'ve started the server', function (done) {
    chai.request('http://127.0.0.1:1121')
        .get('/')
        .end(function(err, response){
            console.log(response.status);
            expect(500).to.equal(400);// This passes? What?
            done();
        });
});

after((done) => {
    dexterServer.tearDown();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Mocha supports promises so you could use the fact that `chai-http` produces promises and just return the promise:

```
it('should\'ve started the server', function () {
    // Return the promise.
    return chai.request('http://127.0.0.1:1121')
        .get('/')
        // Use .then instead of .end.
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response.status);
            expect(500).to.equal(400);
        });
});
```

If you need to do special processing of errors, you could have a `.catch` too. Otherwise, you can let Mocha handle any error as a failure.